# Undefined index when calculating age from an inputted birthdate

Tags: php, html

I am new in this site, and i found some questions that are connected to my system error but unfortunately they can't fix the error. I am creating an offline web-based information system for my capstone project and I don't understand why *P_Bday* is undefined.. Here is my code

This is my code for inputting Birthdate:

```
input type="text" id = "P_Bday" name = "P_Bday" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required
```

And here's my code for calculating age:

```
function ageCalculator($dob){
    if(!empty($dob)){
        $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
        $today   = new DateTime('today');
        $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
        return $age;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

$dob = $_POST["P_Bday"];
```

And I call my function here, where it should display the calculated age depending on the inputted birthdate:

```
input type='text' name = 'P_Age' id='disabledTextInput' class='form-control' value='".ageCalculator($dob)."' readonly
```

Every time I ran my code it says:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: P_Bday in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\PISGDH\recordclerk\RecordEntry\addPatient.php** on line
>   **47**

Comment: Can you show us the <form> tag at the top of your code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask. Also get help formatting markdown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) - Start by removing the `<pre>`and instead indent 4 spaces.

Comment: Is the second input shown on the same page as the first? If you show it before the form is submitted, there will be no POST data available

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score 0):

If the line `$dob = $_POST["P_Bday"];` is being run on the page before anything is sent via `POST`, then `$_POST[foo]` is invalid.

Change the line to:

```
if(isset($_POST["P_Bday"])) $dob = $_POST["P_Bday"];
    else $dob = null;
```

Or:

```
$dob = isset($_POST["P_Bday"]) ? $_POST["P_Bday"] : null;
```

Comment: thanks Ben Pearl Kahan it worked, but the age resulted to "0" every time I input the birthday

Comment: Could you put `var_dump($dob);` after the line above so we can see what the output of `$dob` is?

Comment: I mean, look at it when something has been posted - after you've submitted the form! The reason why I ask is because format of the `datetime` might be incorrect to process the function.

Answer (score 0):

An `Undefined index` error is pretty simple to debug. You start at the file mentioned in the error message `C:\xampp\htdocs\PISGDH\recordclerk\RecordEntry\addPatient.php` and go to the line mentioned in the error message `line 47` and find the undefined index in question on that line `P_Bday` and know with absolute certainty that up to this point in your code you have **not** defined that index for that variable. You can work your way *backwards* through the code to try and figure out your mistake. The mistake can be a typo (you used the wrong case/variable name) or it can be that you just forgot to initialize the variable properly.

The best way to avoid undefined variable/index errors is to **initialize always and initialize early**. In the few cases where you cannot be sure that variables are properly initialized (*for example with `$_POST`/`$_GET` or other external variables under control of client input*) you want to use `isset` to avoid the error and that way you can coalesce null values or write logic that prevents the code from continuing with an uninitialized value in case of user error.

### Example

```
if (!isset($_POST['P_Bday'])) {
    die("You forgot to fill out your birthday!");
} else {
    echo "Yay!";
}
```

---

## Some good initialization techniques with `$_POST`/`$_GET`

A good best practice for "*initialize always and initialize early*" when dealing with user input is to setup a default set of values for the expected input from your form and initialize from that in order not to fall into this trap.

### Example

```
$defaultValues = [
    'P_Bday'  => null,
    'Option1' => 'default',
    'Option2' => 1,
];
/* Let's say the user only supplied Option1 */
$_POST = ['Option1' => 'foo'];
/* This makes sure we still have the other index initialized */
$inputValues = array_intersect_key($_POST, $defaultValues) + $defaultValues;

/**
 * Now you can pass around $inputValues safely knowing all expected values
 * are always going to be initialized without having to do isset() everywhere
 */

doSomething(Array $inputValues) {
    if (!$inputValues['P_Bday']) { // notice no isset() check is necessary
        throw new Exception("You didn't give a birthday!!!");
    }
    return (new DateTime)->diff(new DateTime($inputValues['P_Bday']))->y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variable $dob after calling function. You have to declare your variable before function call and also use conditional statement like following:
Please write your code as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST["P_Bday"])){
    $dob = $_POST["P_Bday"];
} else {
    $dob ="";
}
function ageCalculator($dob){
    if(!empty($dob)){
        $birthdate = new DateTime($dob);
        $today   = new DateTime('today');
        $age = $birthdate->diff($today)->y;
        return $age;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code worked, but the age is still "0" MUHAMMAD IMRAN